# How to disable using .htaccess in sub directories

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a static site with no database.
All the files/pages are with .php extension

I am using .htaccess to make them look as .html for exmaple:-
MY about.php file looks like about.html in the address url.
This is how my .htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php [L,QSA]
```

But now, the Twitter API as well as my Ajax Contact form that uses php is not working anymore !!

Can this somehow is possible that only the url linking in root directory should use the .htaccess
and NOT
the urls going to sub-directories as that might solve the issue.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure it can be done by tweaking the regex a bit:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.html?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

`[^./]+` will match URIs in current directory only and skip the sub-directories.

Comment: Your rule is correct, but its somehow, not working, and I think I voted down by mistake !!

Comment: Being an OP if you downvote an answer without leaving a comment how do you expect someone can help you? This is tested and working rule on my Apache. If it is not working then you will need to provide URLs for which it doesn't work and also specify what error are you getting?